# JUnit for REST: Cannot POST data

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to write a JUnit class for a REST endpoint.

This is my REST method. It works fine.

```
@POST
@Path("create")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public String create(@QueryParam("parentId") String parentId, @QueryParam("name") String name) {
    //do sth.
    return "{\"status\": \"SUCCESS\"}";
}
```

Now my JUnit test looks like that, which doesn't work, because I don't know how to POST my data in the right way:

```
@Test
public void testCreate() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget wt = client.target(REST_MENU_URL + "create");
    String queryParams = "parentId=1&name=NEW_JUnit_NEW";
    // In the line below, I want to POST my query parameters, but I do it wrong 
    Response response = wt.request().post(Entity.entity(queryParams, APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
    // The response has a 500, because the query parameters are all NULL!
    assertEquals("Http code should be 200", 200, response.getStatus());
}
```

So how do I have to change the line with the 'Response' to make it work?
The problem is, that the query parameters (parentId and name) don't get transmitted (response = wt.request().post(...)).

I tried to POST form parameters too, but no success here either. Just like that:

```
Form form =new Form().param("parentId", "4").param("name", "NEW_JUnit_NEW");
Response response = wt.request().post(Entity.entity(form, APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
```

Thanks,
Bernhard

Comment: Did you try setting content-type as TEXT_PLAIN instead of APPLICATION_JSON?

Comment: Where is the JSON? Query parameters nor Form bodies just get converted into JSON like that

Comment: In my create method I added the returned JSON-String. The REST endpoint works in the frontend (so it shouldn't matter, if I return text/html or application/json), but not in the test class, because the query parameters don't get transmitted.

Comment: Ok, why would you want to post query parameters then? Either you should post these parameters as HTTP POST body content or do an HTTP GET with query parameters, you will have to change REST endpoint method in either case.

Comment: I tried _at_FormParam (instead of _at_QueryParam) in my REST endpoint. Result: 415 (wrong media type). _at_QueryParam works fine in the frontend. I agree, _at_QueryParam doesn't look right here, but I cannot make _at_FormParam work in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Jersey Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) documentation, in particular section 5.3.4 on targeting resources.

Query parameters form a part of the URI of the resource, they're not part of the body of the document posted to the resource. You're seeing `null` in your resource because you're not filling in the query parameters in the URI, you're posting them as the body. You need to tell Jersey to put them in the URI...

```
WebTarget wt = client.target(REST_MENU_URL + "create").queryParam("parentId", 1).queryParam("name", "NEW_JUnit_NEW");
```

You'll also need to ensure that your POST request sets the Accept header to allow application/json (by calling the `accept(...)` method after calling `request()`) and you're going to need to construct some kind of Entity to pass to the `post(...)` method - the problem here is that your resource is not consuming the entity body but the client API expects you to send something - this is a code smell which suggests your API is not particularly ReSTful. You can probably get away with some kind of empty body constructed from an empty string. It should look a bit like this...

```
Response response = wt.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.text(""))
```

Alternatively, you could look into converting your API so that it accepts a JSON document and move the query parameters into that document.